# remove shell type from iterm2 tab title

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I checked the documentation and i don't see a way to remove this:
[image]

in case it matters, I'm using oh my zsh, but even if I set the title natively this happens.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Preferences->General->Session Title.

Comment: @chepner it's not there under any of the tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Basics...

Set the Title to Name (only) and the Job Name won't appear